Is there a way in macOS 12's Finder to instantly "Go to Folder" like you could on macOS 10.14?
In Finder on macOS 10.14 when you pressed ⇧⌘G (Go > Go to Folder), typed a path and pressed enter, it would take you there instantly. On macOS 12, it first wants to list all the other subfolders in the main folder that contains the subfolder I want to go to, which can take up to 30 seconds.
What I mean is if I type ~/Documents/Work and press enter, it starts loading and won't take me there before it's listed ~/Documents/Music, ~/Documents/Another_Folder and all other folders within ~/Documents.
Is there a way to change this behaviour in Finder, natively or with a third party solution?

30 seconds? How many subfolders of ~/Documents do you have? Is this a mechanical hard drive, or an SSD? For me, it's pretty instant, but it only lists the sub-items when I type / . What if you type /w together quickly?

@benwiggy Same behaviour regardless. It's an M1 Mac with an SSD. My documents folder does have more than a thousand subfolders, and when I counted now it took 18 seconds. It's a lot faster in directories containing fewer subfolders, but as part of my workflow I have to browse also external HDDs and network folders with many thousand subfolders and whose structure I cannot change, which my Intel Mac on macOS 10.14 did dramatically faster since it didn't have to load suggestions.

I doubt Apple provides options. You could use open in the Terminal instead; and you can navigate the Finder directly by typing filenames with the keyboard.

@benwiggy Thanks, but the Terminal is not an option when for example using the "Go to Folder" function from an application's "Open File" dialog.

You can still navigate swiftly by starting to type the name in a File dialog, as you would in the Finder.
